# How to create pie chart in Java ME?

Tags: java-me, charts

Is there any way of drawing pie chart in Java ME?

Answer (score 3):

You can draw one pie slice using the [fillArc](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Graphics.html#fillArc(int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) method of the Graphics class.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you're going to have to go with low-level drawing using Graphics methods such as fillArc , drawLine etc.

if you're using the high-level UI you can create a new Image, get its Graphics object and draw on that or you could just extend CustomItem.